# Confidence interval for result of multivariate minimization/fitting

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting, confidence-interval, minimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a set of observations [x(t), y(t)], which I try to fit to a certain  assumption: x=Fx(ax, bx, t), y=Fy(ay, by, t). Fx and Fy are linear, but the noise of observations is significantly not gaussian.

For this I perform minimization of a custom-written function F(ax, bx, ay, by, [observations]). I use scipy.optimize.minimize , and get the values of parameters ax, bx, ay, by that minimize F for a given set of observations.

Question 1: how do I estimate, say, 95% confidence area for these results, so that I can see how vague or dependable the answer is?

I believe that the values of parameters are not independent, so the confidence area might not be a 4-rectangular, but rather some blob in the solution space around the minimum point.

Question 2: if I simplify my assumption to linear form: x=ax*t + bx, y=ay*t + by, with noise of observations being 2d gaussian, are there any ready routines in python to do this fitting with calculation of confidence interval of the result?

Answer (score 0):

Lampton, Margon and Bowyer, 1976, Astrophysical Journal, 208, 177

[link to artical on the ADS abstract service](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1976ApJ...208..177L/abstract)

Answer (score 0):

In general case, when distribution of measurement errors is unknown, you can use
resampling approach. For example, take randomly 90% of your measurements and find
estimations, repeat the following process 100 times (or more) with different random subsamples of original measurements. Store all obtained estimates in array. Now, you can find 95-percentile (or whatever you want) for each estimate. That will be a 95%-confidence interval of the estimation.

In case of linear model and gaussian noise, I would suggest to look for packages implementing Kalman filter. They are definitely exist, e.g. [pykalman](https://pykalman.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Now, isn't it possible to get the confidence interval from the 4D shape of minimum into which minimization falls?